# How to identify about month change in input[type=date]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using the input field type=date in react component as shown below.

```
<input
  id="date_export"
  className="date-calender"
  type="date"
  disabled={!this.state.disableCalendar}
  onChange={(event) => this.setState({date: event.target.value})}}
  required={true}
  value={this.state.date} />
```

Now, when the user clicks on the input field, the calendar pops up and there is an up and down arrow to change the month.
[image]

How to identify from the event which arrow gets clicked?

Comment: I think that isn't native event to do this, but you can use date selected as reference

Comment: @PedroFelgueiras I am trying to use the selected date as a reference but it's not solving my problem. What is happening right now, suppose date 6 April is selected and when I click on the upper arrow then the previous months' date gets selected (ex. 6 march).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, It's VERY hard to have a stable code for your answer, but here is an example:

```js
class DateForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dateInput: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
    }
  }
  
  handleChange(e) {
    const { dateInput } = this.state;
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ dateInput:value });
    const monthInput = new Date(value).getMonth();
    const monthState = new Date(dateInput).getMonth();
    const dateOnInput = new Date(value).getDate();
    const dateState = new Date(dateInput).getDate();
    if(dateOnInput === dateState) {
      if(Math.sign(monthInput - monthState == -1)) {
        console.log('Up arrow');
      } else { 
        console.log('Down arrow');
      }
    } 
  }
  
  render() {
    const { dateInput } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="date" value={dateInput} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DateForm />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```